# parse json object in javascript to get key and values

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a object, need to parse the below data

```
  var data= [{"obj1":"2122"},{"obj2":"123"}]
```

to get both the keys and values in javascript. I yried to use:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
for(var prop in data) {
if(data.hasOwnProperty(prop))
  console.log(prop);
}
```

The values that are obtained in console are

```
Object {obj1: "2122"}
Object {obj2: "123"}
```

But I need to access the values seperately and not as object. How to retrieve it from that object?

Comment: Show us the expected output!

Comment: show the expected way and output that you want  ? if you want to parse just like search by the keys ,you can use loadash before search the object ..

Comment: try to use underscore functions, http://underscorejs.org/#pluck

Comment: The post claims to have a [JavaScript] *object*. JSON.parse takes *JSON text*. A useful start would be to omit the incorrect JSON.parse usage - edit the post to remove the incorrect information.

Comment: Are you sure the objects in array is supposed to have different keys? If those values are of same type, you should use same key name and it'll be much simpler.

Comment: why we have to parse here, this is already a perfect valid object ,right?

Answer (score 5):

JSON.parse is use to parse JSONString to Javascript Object.

You can not use it directly on a JavaScript Object ...

Anyway, your object is an array so you may do :

```
var arr = JSON.parse(data);
arr.forEach(function(elementObject){
    var keys = Object.keys(elementObject);
    keys.forEach(function(key){
      console.log(key + ":"+elementObject[key]);
    })
});
```

Cheers

Comment: *"String to JSON"* - no, it's for converting a JSON string (A string that adhere's to JavaScript Object Notation) to JavaScript object. JavaScript Object != JSON

Comment: @Rajeshwar You're welcome, so please mark question as solved, T J you are right !

Answer (score 1):

Here  you will get the values in array "values".

```js
var data= [{"obj1":"2122"},{"obj2":"123"}]
 
data = JSON.stringify(data);
 
var values = [];
 
JSON.parse(data, function (key, value) {

    if (typeof(value) != "object") {
        values.push({[key]:value});
 // values.push(value); //if you need a value array
    }  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use `Array#map` and extract `keys` of the object in the `callback`. Iterate them to gain the `value` of each key using `Array#forEach`

```js
var data = [{
  "obj1": "2122"
}, {
  "obj2": "123"
}];
var op = data.map(function(item) {
  var keys = Object.keys(item);
  var arr = [];
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    arr.push(item[key]);
  });
  return arr;
});
console.log(op);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code use `$.each` function to parse object..

```js
 var data= [{"obj1":"2122"},{"obj2":"123"}]
 $.each(data, function(key, val) {
   $.each(val, function(k, v) {
   console.log('key ='+k);
   console.log('value ='+v);
   alert('key = '+k+', value = '+v);
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one..

```
var obj = JSON.parse('[{"obj1":2122},{"obj2":123}]');
obj.forEach(function(ElementObject){
var keys=Object.keys(ElementObject);
 console.log(keys[0],ElementObject[Object.keys(ElementObject)]); 
}
);
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nisr19/8qr3t3mp/2/)

Answer (score -1):

First:

```
var data = [{"obj1":"2122"},{"obj2":"123"}]
```

This line will create an Array. No need for:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

If you want to access via key/value you need to restructure your data.

```
var data = [{key:"obj1",value:"2122"},{key:"obj2", value:"123"}];
for( var index in data)
{ 
  var item = data[index]; 
  console.log(item.key);
  console.log(item.value);

}
```

Alternately you can map:

```
 var keys = [{
  "obj1": "2122"
}, {
  "obj2": "123"
}];
var op = data.map(function(item) {
  var keys = Object.keys(item);
  var arr = [];
  keys.forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key);
    arr.push(key);
  });
  return arr;
});
var i=0;
for(var i=0;i<op.length;i++)
{
  console.log(i);
  var pair=data[i];
  console.log(pair);
  var key=op[i][0];
  console.log(key);
  var value=pair[key];
  console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: Edit: Updated to answer question without changing data structure.